# How can we implement jquery validation without jquery validator

Tags: jquery

without use of jquery.validate.js validate email in php

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regular expression. Pick one [from here which validates email](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) and apply it to the user input to test whether it matches. In PHP you could use the [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

You can't...you can't not-include code and get all the advantages of it, you have to have code that does the job *somewhere*, this goes for any language.  There are alternatives for sure, none nearly as mature/supported, but you're welcome to try them, for example [here's another popular validation plugin](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/).

If you want just the validation you're after for a specific check, see how it's done [inside the plguin](http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.js) and replicate that in PHP, whether it be length, min/max, regex, etc.